# functools.wraps for python 2.4

Tags: python, python-2.4

[`functools.wraps`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) is not available in python 2.4.Is there any other module which can be used instead of this in python 2.4?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can copy the functools code from Python2.5 and have it work in Python2.4 with only minor changes (substitute a *lambda* for the *partial*):  http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b48e1b48e670/Lib/functools.py#l15

Here's a simple replacement for partial:

```
def partial(func, *args, **kwds):
    "Emulate Python2.6's functools.partial"
    return lambda *fargs, **fkwds: func(*(args+fargs), **dict(kwds, **fkwds))
```

Comment: I tried converting partial to lamda for partial(update_wrapper, wrapped=wrapped,assigned=assigned, updated=updated) but failed.can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on Raymond Hettinger's answer:

```
WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS = ('__module__', '__name__', '__doc__')
WRAPPER_UPDATES = ('__dict__',)
def wraps(wrapped, assigned=WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS, updated=WRAPPER_UPDATES):
  def partial(func, *args, **kwds):
    return lambda *fargs, **fkwds: func(*(args+fargs), **dict(kwds,**fkwds))
  def update_wrapper(wrapper, wrapped, assigned=WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS,
                     updated=WRAPPER_UPDATES):
    for attr in assigned:
      setattr(wrapper, attr, getattr(wrapped, attr))
    for attr in updated:
      getattr(wrapper, attr).update(getattr(wrapped, attr, {}))
    return wrapper
  return partial(update_wrapper, wrapped=wrapped,
                 assigned=assigned, updated=updated)
```